# Draw Boolean property as a button without a icon

Tags: python, scripting, interface, panel

So here is a example Panel and adding a boolean,

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty

bpy.types.Scene.Boolean= BoolProperty(
    name="Boolean",
        description="Example",
        default = True)

class Example_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Example"
    bl_category = "Example"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
   

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        sce = context.scene
        layout.prop(sce, "Boolean")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Example_Panel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Example_Panel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

so that would give a check like this,

[image: Boolean Example]

and to add a icon,

```
layout.prop(sce, "Boolean", icon = 'CHECKMARK')
```

that would give this,

[image: Icon]

so I don't want an icon and at the same time I want a a button like the latter picture.

So far, I do this to not put a Icon to my booleans,

```
layout.prop(sce, "Boolean", icon = 'BLANK1')
```

It gives this,

[image: Solution for now]

But there is a offset to the right which I don't want, so how would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [API Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop) it says:

> toggle (int in [-1, 1], (optional)) – Use toggle widget for boolean values, or a checkbox when disabled (the default is -1 which uses toggle only when an icon is displayed)

So you can use:

```py
layout.prop(sce, "Boolean", toggle = 1)
```

Which gives you exactly what you want:

[image]